# 404 error in Codeigniter URI remapping

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, uri

I get 404 error on remapping codeigniter, here is my scenario:

1-I have a controller: `USER`
2-When my user has logged in, it will redirected to `USER/DASHBOARD` but I don't have any function by name `DASHBOARD` in `USER` controller, I gave it an specific controller by name `DASHBOARD` but when I go to  `USER/DASHBOARD` it gaves me 404 error...

Here is what I've done up to now:

1- my root .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
```

2- my config.php changes:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

3- my routes.php changes:

```
$route['user']="user";
$route['user/dashboard']="dashboard";

$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = "";
```

4- I have index() function in DASHBOARD controller which gives me the output text as below:

```
class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        echo 'tst';
    }
}
```

Your help is appreciated :)

Comment: So you want to do this? Lets see scenario, user logs in and is redirected to user/dashboard and you want to use controller dashboard. Why dont you simply after log in redirect to the /dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this change to **routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = "";
//reserved routes must be first

$route['user/dashboard'] = "dashboard";
//get rid of the user route, what does it do?
```